# Sequence of month end business days according to Australian time-zone

Tags: r, date

My goal is to create a sequence of month-end business days in Australia. I have created the daily sequence below but am unsure how to select the month-end dates from this series.

```
pacman::p_load(RQuantLib)

daysSeq = seq(from = as.Date("2017-08-31"), to = as.Date("2023-08-31"), by = "1 day")
business_days <- data.frame(dates = daysSeq, bizday = isBusinessDay("Australia", daysSeq))
```

The question is similar to: [How to get date of last business day of month in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113346/how-to-get-date-of-last-business-day-of-month-in-r). But I can't get the answers to apply to me.

Comment: Which package does your `isBusinessDay` function come from? It's best practice to include those in your question.

Comment: `library(dplyr); business_days |> mutate(mo = lubridate::floor_date(dates, "month")) %>% filter(dates == max(dates), .by = mo)`

Comment: @JonSpring apologies for that.  It comes from: RQuantLib. Can you please expand on your answer? I do't understand the "|>" syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744605/6851825